# How to do Sticky Bottom Navbar in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: navbar, bootstrap-5

I want to do sticky footer like [this](https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/), but even though i copied it from there, it does not look the same. When i zoom out the page, the navbar will stick to the top, not the bottom. Here is the screenshot:[image: result i got]

Here is my code (which i have said, basically copy from that page):

```
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-CuOF+2SnTUfTwSZjCXf01h7uYhfOBuxIhGKPbfEJ3+FqH/s6cIFN9bGr1HmAg4fQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        .bd-placeholder-img {
            font-size: 1.125rem;
            text-anchor: middle;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
                font-size: 3.5rem;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    
    <header>
      <!-- Fixed navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex">
              <input class="form-control mr-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    
        <!-- Begin page content -->
        <main class="flex-shrink-0">
          <div class="container">
            <h1 class="mt-5">Sticky footer with fixed navbar</h1>
            <p class="lead">Pin a footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS. A fixed navbar has been added with <code class="small">padding-top: 60px;</code> on the <code class="small">main &gt; .container</code>.</p>
            <p>Back to <a href="/docs/5.0/examples/sticky-footer/">the default sticky footer</a> minus the navbar.</p>
          </div>
        </main>
        
        <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-light">
          <div class="container">
            <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
          </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
```

How to do sticky footer like the one from bootstrap example? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be missing the reference to the JS file or CSS files; please try the following.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="h-100" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <title>Sticky Footer Navbar Template · Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
        main > .container {
            padding: 60px 15px 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">

<header>
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
            <button aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler"
                    data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a aria-current="page" class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a aria-disabled="true" class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input aria-label="Search" class="form-control mr-2" placeholder="Search" type="search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<!-- Begin page content -->
<main class="flex-shrink-0">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="mt-5">Sticky footer with fixed navbar</h1>
        <p class="lead">Pin a footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS. A
            fixed navbar has been added with <code class="small">padding-top: 60px;</code> on the <code class="small">main
                &gt; .container</code>.</p>
        <p>Back to <a href="https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sticky-footer/">the default sticky footer</a> minus the navbar.</p>
    </div>
</main>

<footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
    </div>
</footer>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Based on your answer, it looks like im missing on the twitter-bootstrap CDN part. But what is that and where did you get it? I can not find reference to that in the bootstrap starter template.

Comment: It's the CDN from CDNJS. You can use that or download the Bootstrap bundle and reference that.